# How can I change the default 1 hour duration of a new appointment in the iOS calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

My calendar appointments automatically default to an hour for the end of appointment. I am running on iOS 11 on my iPhone.

How do I change the default time to just 1/2 hour?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see anything in the settings app for changing this for the calendars.  Only the default reminder times have a preference.

I use Siri for this and it works great for me

- Hey Siri, make an appointment at 10 A.M. for 15 minutes.
- add a recurring appointment for 30 minutes starting at 9 A.M. on the 28th of every month

  - change the title to review finances